# How do I pass a parameter not in the URL using Angularjs ui-router and components?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I cannot figure out how to pass a parameter using angularjs ui-router, since `$stateParams` has been [depricated](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#stateparams-deprecation) in ui-router 1.x. The ui-router documentation shows an [example](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellosolarsystem#state-parameters) of passing a parameter through the URL, but no examples of passing a parameter that is not included as part of the URL.

```
{
  name: 'person',
  url: '/people/{personId}',
  component: 'person',
  resolve: {
    person: function(PeopleService, $transition$) {
      return PeopleService.getPerson($transition$.params().personId);
    }
  }
}
```

This used to be [possible](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls) using `$stateParams` by adding a params object to the state object.

```
.state('contacts', {
        url: "/contacts",
        params: {
            param1: null
        },
        templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
    })
```

However, this requires the now deprecated `$stateParams`.

I have tried mixing the 2 methods, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
{
  name: 'person',
  url: '/people/',
  component: 'person',
  params:{
    personId:null
  }
  resolve: {
    person: function(PeopleService, $transition$) {
      return PeopleService.getPerson($transition$.params().personId);
    }
  }
}
```

Has this ability been removed from ui-router? Is there a better way to pass parameters, especially objects, without making ridiculous URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the parameters are passed through the `$transition$` object. This object is not passed like a regular provider to the controller though.  You pass the `$transition$` object in through bindings on the component. `$transition$` is automatically bound as is explained [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3110#issuecomment-256204161).

ui-router Config:

```
.state({
        name: "contacts",
        url: "/contacts",
        params: {
            param1: null
        },
        component: "contacts"
    })
```

Controller:

```
module.component("contacts", {
    bindings: { 
        $transition$: '<'
    },
    controller: {
        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.$onInit = function(){
            var param1 = $ctrl.$transition$.params().param1;
        };
    }
}
```

HTML Link

```
<a ui-sref="contacts({param1:$ctrl.myParam})" ui-sref-active="active">Contacts</a>
```

More information on using `$transition$` and `$transition$.params()` can be found on [ui-router's Github page](https://github.com/ui-router/ui-router.github.io/blob/master/_guide/105.ng1-route-to-component.md).